# SQL query to select 1000 companies with 10000 employees

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a database with two tables: **Company** and **Employee**. The Employee table uses the `company_id` column as a foreign key.
Here is the table structure: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qI98x145)

```sql
CREATE TABLE company (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    company_name VARCHAR(255),
    address VARCHAR(255),
    telephone VARCHAR(20),
    fax VARCHAR(20)
);
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    company_id INT,
    address VARCHAR(255),
    telephone VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company(id)
);
```

The **Companies** table contains information on 20,000 companies, and the **Employees** table has data on over 65,000 employees.

I want to write a SQL query that selects 1000 companies such that the total number of employees across these companies adds up to 10,000 employees. Here is what I have so far:

```sql
SELECT c.id, c.company_name, COUNT(e.id) AS total_employees
FROM company c
INNER JOIN employee e ON c.id= e.company_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.company_name
HAVING COUNT(e.id) = 10000
LIMIT 1000;
```

This query seems to provide the number of employees for each company, but I'm struggling to ensure that only 1000 companies are selected and their total number of employees goes up to 10,000.

Comment: Please add an example resembling the structure of your tables (`create table` statements) with some sample/mock data (`insert`), the query you've tried so far, what it returned and what you want it to return instead. At the moment, it sounds like you want a [`limit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html) clause in [CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) or subqueries.

Comment: Again: please add some sample/mock entries and an example result you wish to get based on those. It'll be easier to reproduce the setup and devise, test and demonstrate a query. It's also easier to clarify your criteria looking at a specific example than it is to interpret an abstract description thereof.

Comment: Right now you're selecting a 1000 companies with up to 10'000 employees *each*, not in total.

Comment: @Zegarek- thats right. how to change the code to achieve the above result.

Comment: If you want to get *up to* 1000 companies with *up to* 10000 in total, then a simple stepping sum is enough: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WH3_7vMG). Note that depending on how you order them, you can get very few companies with high numbers of employees, or a 1000 small companies summing up to nowhere near the 10k headcount. If you want *exactly* 1000 with an *exact* total of 10000 employees (or a set with a ratio as close to 1k:10k as possible), then there's a balancing element to the task.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get up to 1000 companies with up to 10000 in total, then a simple stepping sum is enough. Note that depending on how you order them, you can get very few companies with high numbers of employees, or a 1000 small companies summing up to nowhere near the 10k headcount.

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/WH3_7vMG)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT *, SUM(company_employees)OVER w1 AS total_employees_stepping_sum
     FROM 
       (SELECT e.company_id, c.company_name, COUNT(*) AS company_employees
        FROM company c
        INNER JOIN employee e ON c.id = e.company_id
        GROUP BY 1,2) AS subquery1
     WINDOW w1 AS (order by company_employees 
                   rows between unbounded preceding
                        and     current row)
    ) AS subquery2
WHERE total_employees_stepping_sum<=10000
ORDER BY total_employees_stepping_sum DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

| company_id | company_name | company_employees | total_employees_stepping_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10614 | name_of_company_10614 | 2 | 10000 |
| 5984 | name_of_company_5984 | 2 | 9998 |
| 15782 | name_of_company_15782 | 2 | 9996 |
| 12098 | name_of_company_12098 | 2 | 9994 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

If you want exactly 1000 with an exact total of 10000 employees (or a set with a ratio as close to 1k:10k as possible), then there's a balancing element to the task.